# Should an event handler be an anonymous function and should it have named funtion/s inside?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

When you have a function like this

```
function setStreamController(event) {
    do some stuff
}
```

What is the difference between the following two pieces of code?

Code A

```
$('#play-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    setStreamController(event);
});
```

Code B

```
$('#play-btn').on('click', setStreamController);
```

I heard Code B looks like a eval() function so the code must be Code A.

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same. The only difference between them is using anonymous function or using named function.

Personally, I would prefer to use named function because I can use multiple times when required.

Comment: My point is whether or not there is any difference between an event handler that is an anonymous function having a named function in it and an event handler that itself is a named function.